# Array - Get Counts Group by Two Indexes

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have array similar to following array. But there are more than **2000 main items.**

- [2] of inside array is either "type1" or "type2". There is no any
  other value.
- [1] of inside array are years. It can be 1990,1991.......,2017. Next
  year it goes to 2018..........
- [0] of inside array is a ID and it isn't related to this question.

```
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1134
            [1] => 2014
            [2] => type1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1133
            [1] => 2014
            [2] => type1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1132
            [1] => 2014
            [2] => type2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1131
            [1] => 2014
            [2] => type2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1130
            [1] => 2013
            [2] => type1
        )
```

**What I need**

I want to get following output (all count by year with type).

Count of 1990 type1 = 3 items
Count of 1990 type2 = 65 items
Count of 1991 type1 = 5 items
Count of 1991 type2 = 12 items
............

............

............
............
Count of 2017 type1 = 5 items
Count of 2017 type2 = 10 items

Comment: Where does the data come from? If it is a database, you should count and group the items there in sql. If you need to do it in php, what do you have so far and where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: It is comes from WordPress DB, so data in store in not same table. So i can't use the count and group....

Comment: Have you tried anything? It is not that hard, a simple [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) is enough.

Comment: @axiac I tried. The way I used is really hard, need lot of time.. What I do is create variable like $_1990_type1_count; $_1990_type2_count; $_1991_type1_count;....................... Then I used  $_1990_type1_count++ with if condition inside loop... It will take lots of time... So I stoped it

Comment: That's not the right way to do it. Use an two-levels [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) to store the values grouped by year and then, for each year, by type (or vice-versa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an other array that will store the count for each year like this one :

```
Array(year => Array(type1 => count, type2 =>count), ...)
```

Then loop your array, and count :

```
$tab = array( 
0 => Array
    (
        0 => 1134,
        1 => 2014,
        2 => 'type1'
    ),

1 => Array
    (
        0 => 1133,
        1 => 2014,
        2 => 'type1'
    ),

2 => Array
    (
        0=> 1132,
        1 => 2014,
        2 => 'type2'
    ),

3 => Array
    (
        0 => 1131,
        1 => 2014,
        2 => 'type2'
    ),

4 => Array
    (
        0 => 1130,
        1 => 2013,
        2 => 'type1'
    ));

$yeartab = array();

foreach($tab as $elt){
    $year = $elt[1];
    $type = $elt[2];
    if(array_key_exists($year, $yeartab)){
        if(array_key_exists($type,$yeartab[$year]))
            $yeartab[$year][$type]++;
        else
            $yeartab[$year][$type] = 1;
    } else {
        $yeartab[$year][$type] = 1;
    }
}

print_r($yeartab);
```

This will output :

```
Array ( 
 [2014] => Array ( [type1] => 2 [type2] => 2 ) 
 [2013] => Array ( [type1] => 1 ) 
)
```

Comment: Thanks. You saved lots of time :-)